# perform data list/arry set from API in sharedpreference dynamically on flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter, api, dart

I have a data object from the data api that contains an array so that if data object 1 is empty it will move the data index to the same object

example when I set string to pref

```
 prefs.setString('first_name', response['data']['first_name']);
```

here i try to make list
// Code For List

```
  prefs.setStringList('amount', response['data_finance']['amount']);
```

API DATA OBJECT // p_co_id , code , description , amount
//

Comment: means you want to save array in sharedpreferences?

Comment: yes, and create data on the object if it is empty it will move to the next index